# PDO Connection and Insert

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert, pdo

I am new to using PDO and I have no clue what is wrong with it. It says i have this error
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING on line 3 Here is my code that goes along with it.

```
<?php
include 'dbconnect.php';
$sql = "INSERT INTO event (name,location,admission,map,additional,featured,description)    VALUES (:name,:location,:admission,:map,:additional,:featured,:description)";
$q = $conn->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':name'=>$_POST['name'],
      ':location'=>$_POST['location'],
      ':admission'=>$_POST['addmission'],
      ':map'=>$_POST['map'],
      ':additional'=>$_POST['additional'],
      ':featured'=>$_POST['featured'],
      ':description'=>$_POST['description']));
?>
```

Comment: Why are you quoting the `$_POST` variables?

Comment: Why are you wrapping your POST vars in double quotes? That's completely unnecessary. Also, can you post the contents of your include?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the double quotes from all of these `$_POST` variables. There is no need to quote them, and indeed it causes harm if you also quote their array keys.

```
$name= $_POST['name'];
$location =  $_POST['location'];
$admission =    $_POST['admission'];
$map =   $_POST['map'];
$additional  =  $_POST['additional'];
$featured  =  $_POST['feature'];
$description =   $_POST['description'];
```

Inside a double-quoted string, if referencing array keys, you must not quote the keys, or surround the whole thing in `{}`.  But *neither* is necessary here.

```
echo "In a double quoted string, you can use $array[keys] unquoted, or surround quoted {$array['keys']} in {}";
// But this is a syntax error! (like you are getting)
echo "Don't quote the $array['keys'] if inside a double quote string, not wrapped in {}";
```

In fact, there is no real need to assign them to variables at all.  Just use the `$_POST` inputs directly in the `execute()` call.

```
$q->execute(array(':name'=>$_POST['name'],
          ':location'=>$_POST['location'],
          ':admission'=>$_POST['addmission'],
          ':map'=>$_POST['map'],
          ':additional'=>$_POST['additional'],
          ':featured'=>$_POST['featured'],
          ':description'=>$_POST['description']));
```

Comment: Ok I changed everything above but I am still getting errors and do i need the array and do I need to change the values?

Comment: @maxgee You totally edited your code above...  You do need the array keys like `':featured' => $_POST['featured']` in the execute array, just as I have it above.

Comment: Ok i edited my code but the data is still isnt going into my data base

Comment: @maxgee Then you need to check PDO's `errorInfo()` http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php Are you sure your connection is even correctly established?

Comment: I also see that `$_POST['admission']` is misspelled, though that will result in a blank value (unless the column doesn't permit nulls), not a query failure.

Comment: I thought this was the right code for it? <?php
$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "name";
$dbuser     = "user";
$dbpass     = "password";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
?>

Answer (score 0):

The error may be referring to the use of double quotes around the $_POST variables.

The error is syntax on Line 3 which appears to have nothing to do with the title of this question.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

As for PDO, you must have that sort of code in the included dbconnect.php file as no PDO related code is visible in the question.